# Are the text elements in Smartforms ever interpreted as if they were SAPScript texts?

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

So as I see, the text elements of a Smartform are (at least very similar in nature to) SAPScript texts.
[image]

I can even include Sapscript commands in the Smartform text, and they show as if they did something.
[image]

When I test my form however, it seems that the commands are ignored.
[image]

So my question is: is there a reason why these texts commands are not interpreted? Can they be interpreted inside a Smartform, or is this just a side effect of the fact that the same editor is used to open these texts?

Background:
I'm asking this because i have to check for hardcoded logic inside Smartforms, and I'm curious if commands in the text could ever be regarded as "logic", or whether they would always get ignored.

Also, I am aware that the "Conditions" tab of basically every element is used for introducing logic, such that the element is only executed if the conditions are true.

I am also aware of the fact that there is an element called "Condition", and I'm aware of what that does.

I just whant to know if this particular way of writing logic in SAPScripts is ever executed in Smartforms.

**[EDIT]** Editionally, I'd like to know if the `PERFORM` command in Sapscript texts is ever executable from a smartform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not processed. You can enter them because the same text editor is used, but they will be ignored. `PERFORM` is not supported either.

Comment: you wouldn't happen to have a link to some documentation, would you? - thx :)

Comment: @vlad-ardelean: [http://l m g t f y .com/?q=site%3Ahelp.sap.com+smartforms](https://www.google.de/#q=site:help.sap.com+smartforms) :-p